Is there a source for US patents in pdf format where the text is copy and pasteable?
I downloaded patents from Google patents or lens.org or the uspto. But all those patents are not text-formatted but images. That means you cannot highlight as nicely and more important cannot copy/paste the text. For instance following long URLs in patents requires me to type letter by letter the url text. Is there any source with better formattet pdfs?
edit: some patents downloaded from google patents are text-pdfs, some not.

Paid search services generally provide a searchable PDF. Also, you can take the PDF from Google or The Lens and use an OCR program to make it the way you want it.
It may not be as convenient but Google and other free search engines provide a full text version. You can copy and paste it into a word processor and underline, capture URLs, etc.

Interesting, Google Patents has text pdfs where others do not have, yet others at Google are still image only, like https://patents.google.com/patent/US11514113B2/en . The situation is more fuzzy than I expected and that is presmuably related to the fact that patents quite always have images. Thank you so much for all your helpful work here George.

I think you misunderstood the answer. The Google pdfs are not searchable but Google separately  provides  the full text.
